# JAVA Servidor MySQL con appServ se cae

Tags: java, mysql, appserv

Hola amigos actualmente tengo un problema con una aplicación que hice en el trabajo, como muchas áreas están teniendo acceso al sistema en cuestión, en procesos de las conexiones en appServ me llegan a aparecer mas de 100 procesos y especiales horas pico como por ejemplo antes de ir a comer o antes de la salida que es cuando las áreas ya están preparando todo para irse, el servidor se cae, cabe señalar que solo realizan consultas son muy contaditos con la palma de mi mano quienes hacen modificaciones a todo lo que se tiene almacenado en la BD, pero repito el servidor se cae en horas pico, después de un uso intenso y eso que estamos hablando de un lugar aislado, una red interna donde a lo mucho habrán unos 80 usuarios al día conectándose al sistema, pero después de sobrepasar sus limites aparece este error:

java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: can't create a new trhead (errno 12); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug

buscando en internet me dicen que aumente los limites de conexión, y el limite de uso de memoria RAM esto ya lo hice, hasta exageradamente le puse 10000 eso que le iba a poner mil conexiones pero se me fue un cero dejándolo así porque es muy poco probable que llegue a haber mas de 200 usuarios conectados, el lugar repito es un lugar totalmente restringido, es una red interna y son menos de 200 personas que se conectan al sistema, ¿Qué otra cosa puedo hacer para solventar el problema? la aplicación esta echa en java y utilizo appserv como apoyo para gestionar la base de datos.

¡De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda y pronta respuesta!

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero me parece que tu pregunta tendría mejor cabida en [sf], aunque dicho sitio está en inglés. De todas formas, antes de que intentes hacer la pregunta en dicho sitio, te sugiero que leas tanto allí como aquí, los apartados [ask] y que también realices el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: No sabemos si es problema de recursos asignados, si hay consultas mal hechas, si estás o no liberando las conexiones después de usarlas, si estás o no liberando la memoria después de usarla, si hay un problema de configuración. Que te diga que no puedes crear un hilo habla de que se está agotando el heap. La pregunta es muy amplia ahora mismo, debes hacer profiling y revisar que tu app no tenga memory leaks.

Comment: las consultas si se finalizan, de echo al cerrar la aplicacion igual se finaliza, implemente un metodo que despues de que el sistema detecte inactividad del usuario este se cierre en 2 minutos solo que sigue el problema, investigando vi sobre un psoible bug en el appserv que se solventa con los nuevos, voy a ver si cambio a una version nueva solo que necesito hablar con otro compañero de otra area ya que hay otros sistemas dependientes del mio.

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero mires variables de configuración del MySQL, habilita log(s) para detectes si es una consulta en particular (deberás optimizarla) o momento que ocurre. No fue en MySQL (recién tuve ciertos problemas con MariaDB); te comento que necesite configurar servidor a fin de aprovechar recursos. Son muchas variables que pueden configurarse así como algunas son por cálculos. Busca como cerrar explícitamente las conexiones; puede queden muchas *colgadas*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java